# how to select only status using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hi coders I have a string of statement where I have to fetch only status in it

```
TKT-2297433475972        RCI-                     1A  LOC-696L9U
OD-NYCNYC  SI-      FCMI-K   POI-DCA  DOI-02JUN14  IOI-49881134
1.SINGH/BALJINDER           ADT              ST
1 OJFK KU 102   C 03JUN2145 OK CLRTUS5       F              2PC // Want this F
2 XKWI KU 381   C 04JUN2230 OK CLRTUS5       F              2PC // Want this F
3 ODEL KU 382   C 20JUN0555 OK CLRTUS5       O              2PC // Want this 0
4 XKWI KU 117   C 20JUN0905 OK CLRTUS5       I   08JUN      2PC // Want this I
JFK
FARE     I          IT     // Don't want this I
TOTALTAX USD       462.04
TOTAL                  IT
/FC NYC KU X/KWI KU DEL M/BT CLRTUS5 KU X/KWI KU NYC M/BT CLRTUS
5 END XT5.50YC17.50US17.50US5.00XA7.00XY2.50AY1.60YX25.08IN11.51
YM20.70IN3.65WO4.50XF JFK4.5

TKT-0017434068283-284    RCI-                     1A  LOC-69DQPQ
OD-AUSAUS  SI-      FCMI-I   POI-DCA  DOI-03JUN14                                
1.MIMBELA/JAIME JOSE        ADT               ST
1 OAUS AA 290   M 02JUL1005 OK MHXE1NA/CONS   O   02JUL02JUL 1PC // Want this 0
2 XJFK AA  66   M 02JUL1730 OK MHXE1NA/CONS   O   02JUL02JUL 1PC // Want this 0
3  BCN    ARNK
4 OFCO AA 111   L 29JUL1115 OK LHXETNI4/CONS  O   29JUL29JUL 1PC // Want this 0
5 XORD AA1398   L 29JUL2040 OK LHXETNI4/CONS  O   29JUL29JUL 1PC // Want this 0
AUS
FARE   I               IT// Don't want this I
TOTALTAX USD       639.21
TOTAL                  IT
```

in the above string i have to fetch only ST

like this for first

```
F
F
O
I
```

At present i m using this regex **(?:\s[A-Z]{1}\s\s)**

by using this regex it also give me value of **I** in front of **FARE** which i don't want how can i get only ST but not **I** present in after FARE.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You don't need that. The file looks like it it uses fixed length, so basically every line after 1.SIGH at pos 46 has the status. Where the status ends and where not is up to you. I have no idea what format the snippet has. If you can define the rules of how the layout is constructed you will find your solution

Comment: @Samuel pos may vari its not fix and i dont want to select ST i just want its value

Comment: Ok, select the first non whitespace char after CLRTUS5. Let me guess, this my vary too? As I said, you need to provide the rules for this.

Comment: this string is just an example there are bunch of string let me edit my question and you will get what i want

Comment: Ok: Next solution: Remove first two lines and everything after the 7th. Then apply your regex.

Answer (score 2):

You know, we are just guessing, but what's with that:

```
^\d .+?\W{2}([A-Z]) \W{2}
```

Get the second matching group for that

Here a visual explanation: https://www.debuggex.com/r/kAjngGwRrsHQARYE

To be precise: This works with Ignore Case but which is more important: The Multi line switch must be set so that ^ matches the beginning of a line.

Here is C# Code for you

```
var foo = "1 OJFK KU 102   C 03JUN2145 OK CLRTUS5       F              2PC";

var r = new Regex(@"^\d .+?\W{2}([A-Z]) \W{2}",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

var m = r.Matches(foo);

Console.WriteLine(m[0].Groups[1]);
```

Comment: have you tried it some where as it not selecting any single char

Comment: See my edit, it does its work. You need the Multiline switch for that.

Comment: i dont want to select the whole line my friend only single char in each line which is present below ST

Comment: @Amitesh I said use the second matching group, it contains only the char.

Comment: @Samuel : This Regex will be work -> ^\s\d.+?\W{1}([A-Z]) \W{2}

Answer (score 2):

Hi samuel and anurag thanks for your help with regex of anurag and idea of samuel i made some change and get the out what i desire. This is my code:

```
string foo = @"

TKT-2207434010779-780 RCI- 1A LOC-68XMG5
OD-HOUHOU SI- FCMI-F POI-NYC DOI-02JUN14 IOI-10729143

1.WAHBA/REDA ADT ST
1 OIAH LH7620UA L 07JUN2050 OK LHHNC5N/CN05 F 07JUN07JUN 1PC
2 XLHR LH 911 L 08JUN1645 OK LHHNC5N/CN05 F 08JUN08JUN 1PC
3 XFRA LH 584 L 08JUN2130 OK LHHNC5N/CN05 F 08JUN08JUN 1PC
4 OCAI LH 585 L 06JUL0340 OK LHHNC5N/CN05 O 06JUL06JUL 1PC
5 XFRA LH 440 L 06JUL1000 OK LHHNC5N/CN05 O 06JUL06JUL 1PC
IAH
FARE F USD 522.00
TOTALTAX USD 656.80
TOTAL USD 1178.8
";

StringReader reader = new StringReader(foo);
string line;
List<string> list = new List<string>();
while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
{
   Regex r = new Regex(@"^\s\d.+?\W{1}([A-Z]) \W{2}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
   if(r.IsMatch(line)){
   MatchCollection m = r.Matches(line);
   string value = m[0].Groups[1].ToString();
   list.Add(value); 
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w \w+ \w+ \w+\s+(?<YourVar>\w+)
```

This would work. but it is hard to create a reg expression with just one sample. When using the regex above, every match should contain a group called "YourVar" which contains the desired value

Comment: gave you one more example hope this will help to create one

Comment: this is not working mate i only want to select that character under ST not the whole line mate

Comment: what is the meaning of yourvar

Comment: @AcidJunkie : which value put in the YourVar place ?

Comment: this is called a named group capture. in the match object, there is a property called groups. when you access this like `match.Groups["YourVar"].Value` you get the desired value. But i just realized, that it is really hard to use a regex for this. maybe a custom parser would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

I checked follwing in my code and it is working.

```
Regex.Match(s, @"\W{2}([A-Z])\W{2}").Value.Trim()
```